# Maintaining ViewState for FileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, webforms, viewstate

I am creating [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) controls at run time. When I click a `LinkButton` a new `FileUpload`  control is generated.

Now suppose I have selected a file from a `FileUpload` control and I click the `LinkButton`. The previous `FileUpload` control loses its path. However, I'm maintaining the ViewState of each control that I create at runtime by using this line:

```
f1.enableviewstate = true;
```

How do I maintain the selected file for a `FileUpload` control?

Answer (score 3):

**Steps**

1. user selects a file
2. user click LinkButton (issues a postback that adds additional file uploading control)
3. server side should get the file on postback and store it somewhere (anywhere)
4. replace first `<input type=file>` with something like Label and check mark icon (to tell user the file has already been uploaded (or even a read-only text box with disabled *browse* button to fake file upload control - however you won't be able to display correct file path in it)
5. user is presented with a new form that has new empty file upload control in showing already uploaded files.

For security reasons you can't manipulate `<input type=file>` in any way shape or form.

**Hack approach**
If I understood you correctly your link button adds additional file upload controls to your page. Instead I'd create a sufficient number of upload controls the first time and display just one. Others would be hidden by CSS. After user clicks the LinkButton, it would however have only client-side Javascript functionality that would reveal additional control. And another... and another... and another... until maximum is reached.

**Complex approach**
You could however make it in a different way by using more Javascript and make it more Web 2.0-ish. You should however upload those files via `<iframe>`

Answer (score 2):

as some of the others mentioned, you cannot preserve the viewstate of a FileUpload due to security issues.
What you could do is to simply add a Label just below the FileUpload. When the user clicks on the linkbutton in order to generate a new FileUpload, a postback will be fired where you could check whether the FileUpload controls present on the page have some value (i.e. the user already selected a file to upload), and if so, you could directly start to upload that file and show the result (the path or filename) on the label, just that the user knows he has added that file already. You could also hide the fileupload and additionally add a remove link to again remove the uploaded file (similar approach as Gmail does).

Hope this helped.

Juri

Answer (score 1):

You can't pre-select a file path in the file upload input tag (security related - the user *must* select the file), so .Net is not able to populate the value from viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider if you really need to at it at runtime?
2. If you really need to at runtime; Don't forget to add it to the closest container's `Controls` property. Doing this makes sure it's state is serialized to the `ViewState`.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

as per me there is no way to persist viewstate of fileupload in asps.net.

u can store it's value in hidden field,session etc file u can not be able to assign that value to again file upload because it is read only